# How manipulate this SQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$lastquery = $db->query("
(SELECT l.pid as firstpost, l.islike as islike, t.username as username, l.thumbsup, t.subject as subject, l.dateline as dateline 
FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."thumbspostrating l
LEFT JOIN   ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON (t.firstpost = l.pid)
WHERE thumbsup)
UNION
(SELECT   t.firstpost, ' ' as islike, t.username as username, ' ' as nomames, t.views as views, t.dateline as dateline
FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t)
ORDER BY dateline DESC  
LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$perpage).", ".$perpage);


while ($post = $db->fetch_array($lastquery)) {

if ($post['islike'] == 1) { 
$template .= 'This is a like '.$post['firstpost'].'<br><br>';  
}    
else {
$template .= 'This is a post '.$post['firstpost'].' and '.$post['views'].'<br><br>';
}

}

echo $template;
```

I just want to separate the like post of the thread post

something like this:

```
$post['views'] <-- from second UNION,

$post['pid'] <-- from the first table
```

I know that I can do this kind of stuff "l.pid as firstpost" and order this by the same type of data.

I was doing this:

```
if ($post['islike'] == 1) { 
$template .= 'This is a  like '.$post['firstpost'].'<br><br>';  
}    
else {
$template .= 'This is a post '.$post['firstpost'].' and '.$post['views'].'<br><br>';
}
```

Something that am I missing?

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: None, I just wanna know if I can do something different, because I wanna use $post['t.subject'] and $post['l.pid'] but obviously I can't do this I need to do something like l.pid as pid and the same with the other UNION but I do not want to put a t.pid as pid in the second UNION, something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastquery = $db->query(" 
SELECT  l.dateline as dateline, l.islike, u.username as username 
FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."thumbspostrating l
LEFT JOIN   ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON (t.firstpost = l.pid)
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users u ON (u.uid = l.uid)
UNION
SELECT t.dateline as dateline, ' ', u.username as username
FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."users u ON (u.uid = t.uid)
ORDER BY dateline DESC  
LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$perpage).", ".$perpage);


while ($post = $db->fetch_array($lastquery)) {

if ($post['islike'] == 1) { 
$template .= 'Esto es un like '.$post['dateline'].' user '.$post['username'].'<br><br>';  
}    
else {
$template .= 'Esto es un post '.$post['dateline'].' ademas '.$post['username'].'<br><br>';
}

}
```

RESOLVED

Answer (score 0):

You need to select in second request the same columns like in the first. If you need an additional values you need add these column in first request. To be short - duplicate the first request with another condition. Dose not metter how your alias names the values of second request will be avaliable by the first request aliases and in the same order.